# How to store result in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a report using python where for loop iterates for each location but once i run this code it only gives data for last location.How can i store result from this loop.

```
import inflect
import pandas as pd  

add_sum_data=pd.read_excel("~Add_Summary_17062018.xlsx")

location_code=add_sum_data.iloc[0:,0]

for GO in location_code:    
    ag_row_data = add_sum_data.loc[add_sum_data["location"]== GO]
```

Comment: usually, you'd set up an empty list and append values to it, or use list comprehensions. google for plenty of existing examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for that:

```
results = list()
for GO in location_code:    
    results.append(add_sum_data.loc[add_sum_data["location"]== GO])
```

`results` contains all results.

To access items in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) use integer indexes from `0` to [`len(results) - 1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
results[0], results[1], results[2], ..., results[len(results) - 1]
```

Comment: This is really helpful!!

Comment: I have got results as a list which has multiple dataframes in it for each location.how can I access these data frames

Comment: @rahulbuttan Added explanation in answer